# Display chart in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

I am making graphs using vuejs, get data through laravel API.

```
  data() {
  return {
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    data: {
          labels: [1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020],
          datasets: [{
          data: [70, 95, 100, 120, 257, 271, 300, 321, 383, 450],
          label: 'User Active',
          borderColor: '#3e95cd'
          }
         ]
        },
   options: {
     title: {
       display: true,
       text: 'Report user'
     },
     }
    },
    created() {
       axios
          .get("/project/api/user")
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data); //Result {"datasets":[{"label":"User active","data":[10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"fill":false,"borderColor":"#9ec6cb"}],"labels":["2021-09-07","2021-09-08","2021-09-09","2021-09-10","2021-09-11","2021-09-12","2021-09-13","2021-09-14"]};
          })
    },
    methods: {
       changevalue() {
         axios
          .get("/project/api/user", {
            params: {
              startDate: this.startDate,
              endDate: this.endDate
           } 
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
          })
     }
    }
```

**Template :**

```
<chartjs-component-line-chart
      :data="data"
      :options="options"
      :plugins="plugins"
    />
```

Now I want to get `res.data` data in `created()` instead of default data in `data()`.

And I have a start and end date to choose from, and a submit button.
I want when I select the start and end date and click submit, the chart data will be updated again

```
          <b-form-group>
              <label>Start date:</label>
              <b-form-datepicker
                v-model="startDate"
                :value="startDate"
                :date-format-options="{
                  day: '2-digit',
                  month: '2-digit',
                  year: 'numeric',
                }"
              />
            </b-form-group>
          </b-col>
          <b-col cols="12" md="4" class="mb-md-0 mb-2">
            <b-form-group>
              <label>End date:</label>
              <b-form-datepicker
                v-model="endDate"
                :value="endDate"
                :date-format-options="{
                  day: '2-digit',
                  month: '2-digit',
                  year: 'numeric',
                }"
              />
            </b-form-group>

             <b-button
                variant="primary"
                class="btn-tour-finish"
                @click="changevalue"
              >
```

Please help me. Actually I haven't found the solution yet. I'm also a Vuejs newbie so it's really hard for me. I've been doing it for 2 days now and it still doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All of your code looks correct. It looks like your final step is to set the data from your API into your graph:

```
created() {
   axios
      .get("/project/api/user")
      .then((res) => {
        this.data = res.data.datasets[0].data
}
```

same in your `changevalue()` method:

```
changevalue() {
     axios
      .get("/project/api/user", {
        params: {
          startDate: this.startDate,
          endDate: this.endDate
       } 
      })
      .then((res) => {
        this.data = res.data.datasets[0].data
      })
 }
```

Comment: I pass data from `created()` to `data()` still not working. Data has the format : `{datasets: Array(3), labels: Array(8)}` but when passed to this.data it becomes the format : `{__ob__: Observer}
datasets: (...)
labels: (...)` should not be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this problem..I want to share with you.Can help you newbies like me :

```
data() {
  return {
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    loaded: false,
    data: {
          labels: null,
          datasets: null,
        },
   options: {
     title: {
       display: true,
       text: 'Report user'
     },
     }
    },
    created() {
       this.loaded = false;
       axios
          .get("/project/api/user")
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data); //Result {"datasets":[{"label":"User active","data":[10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"fill":false,"borderColor":"#9ec6cb"}],"labels":["2021-09-07","2021-09-08","2021-09-09","2021-09-10","2021-09-11","2021-09-12","2021-09-13","2021-09-14"]};

          //handle code
          var result = JSON.parse(res.data);
          this.data.labels = result.labels;
          this.data.datasets = result.datasets;
          this.loaded = true;
          })
    },
    methods: {
       changevalue() {
         this.loaded = false;
         axios
          .get("/project/api/user", {
            params: {
              startDate: this.startDate,
              endDate: this.endDate
           } 
          })
          .then((res) => {
            var result = JSON.parse(res.data);
            this.data.labels = result.labels;
            this.data.datasets = result.datasets;
            this.loaded = true
          })
     }
    }





<chartjs-component-line-chart
      v-if="loaded"
      :data="data"
      :options="options"
      :plugins="plugins"
    />
```

Document : [enter link description here](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).